# Make execvp permission denied

Tags: permissions, makefile, execvp

I've got a makefile I'm trying to run without too much luck. Here's what happens

I try to make, and it start out ok. It then gives an error that it can't find the file. However, I can do an ls -ld on the file without any problem. Do you have any idea whats going on?

```
pgr@pgr:~/start_code_1$ make
gcc -Wall -g -m32 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-builtin bootblock.s
ld -nostartfiles -nostdlib -melf_i386 -Ttext 0x0 -o bootblock bootblock.o
gcc -c -o createimage.o createimage.c
gcc -o createimage createimage.o
gcc -Wall -g -m32 -c -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -fno-builtin kernel.s
ld -nostartfiles -nostdlib -melf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel kernel.o
./createimage.given --extended ./bootblock ./kernel
make: ./createimage.given: Command not found
make: *** [image] Error 127
pgr@pgr:~/start_code_1$ ls -ld ./createimage.given 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pgr pgr 26110 Sep 16 13:03 ./createimage.given
```

**UPDATED**

pgr@pgr:~/workspace/318/bootloader$ file createimage.given 
createimage.given: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

**UPDATE 2**

```
pgr@pgr:~/phdvdev/workspace/318/bootloader$ ldd createimage.given 
    not a dynamic executable
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `createimage.given` script has wrong interpreter in shebang line. And the chances are it's been edited on windows machine and has trailing carriage return :)

Comment: Thanks for responding -- I believe createimage.given is a compiled executable c program, not a script. How would I check for the trailing carriage return?

Comment: Well, if it's binary, then it's likely to still use the wrong interpreter, like `ld.so` or whatever. Highly platform specific.

Comment: The same goes for checking for carriage return. `vim` should be of help. But then yes, since you're compiling createimage, it's indeed likely to be binary

Comment: I believe the .createimage.given should be ok -- it was given to an entire group of people, and it seems to work for everyone else but me. Do you have any other ideas

Comment: Doe the people in entire group have identical systems? platform, version, etc.?

Comment: First things first, what is the output of `file createimage.given`?

Comment: and your system is i386? 32bit?

Comment: next step would probably be `ldd createimage.given`.

Comment: That's weird. File says `dynamically linked (uses shared libs)` and ldd says `not a dynamic executable`…